# ViewPager/SectionsAdapter data lost when paging/rotating

Tags: javascript, android

I've tried to solve this riddle with all the related answers but I cant seem to connect the dots.

I have 4 tabs in my MainActivity (code below) which works fine, displaying a list of products in each tab.

When a product is clicked, the id of the record is passed to the ViewProduct Activity (code below) in which the id is used to populate the details of the product and again passed to the 4 fragments though bundles to display the items related to that product.

All of this "List Loading" and "Passing" of parameters works fine, however the ViewPager/SectionsAdaptor is acting funny...

At first tab1, tab3 and tab4 is good, but tab2 is blank, then when you "page" to tab4 and back to tab1, tab1 is blank etc. etc. It seems the page/fragment is loaded twice and this may be the cause of the problem.

So, individually all the fragments work correctly. Why is this happening??
Please help!

Note: I have left out some irrelevant code such as setting TextViews etc. and replace it with comments, so Note the comments and also advise which Activity to extend

Thank you

**This is my MainActivity.java**

```
      public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

            private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
            private AddUpdateProductOps productOps;
            private ViewPager mViewPager;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
                Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
                setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

   mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                int id = item.getItemId();

                if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                    return true;
                }

                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }

            public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

                public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
                    super(fm);
                }

                @Override

                public Fragment getItem(int position) {

                    switch (position) {
                        case 0:
                            Products tab1 = new Products();
                            return tab1;
                        case 1:
                            Sales tab2 = new Sales();
                            return tab2;
                        case 2:
                            Orders tab3 = new orders();
                            return tab3;
                        case 3:
                            Clients tab4 = new Clients();
                            return tab4;
                        default:
                        return null;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public int getCount() {
                    // Show 3 total pages.
                    return 4;
                }

                @Override
                public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
                    switch (position) {
                        case 0:
                            return "Products";
                        case 1:
                            return "Sales";
                        case 2:
                            return "Orders";
                        case 3:
                            return "Clients";
                    }
                    return null;
                }

            }
```

**This is my ViewProduct.jave **

```
 public class ViewProduct extends AppCompatActivity {

        private Button actionButton1;
        private Product oldProduct;
        private long productId;
        private AddUpdateProductOps productOps;
        private TextView EditTextNo;
        private TextView EditTextOrigin, ..., ..., ..., ...;
        private TextView tv_banner_txt;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.view_product);

            final Context[] context = new Context[1];
            productId = getIntent().getLongExtra(EXTRA_PRODUCT_ID,0);
            if (productId < 1){
                productId = Long.parseLong(getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_PRODUCT_IDE));
            }

            oldProduct = new Product();
            productOps = new AddUpdateProductOps(this);

    >Some TextViews are set over here.....(not Included) - findViewById(....) - No >Problem

            actionButton1.setText("EDIT");
            tv_banner_txt.setText("VIEW THE PRODUCT");
            initializeProduct(productId);

         mSectionsPagerAdapter = new ViewProduct.SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

            mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
            mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

            TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager,false);

            GradientDrawable border = new GradientDrawable();
            border.setStroke(7, 0xFF000000); //black border with full opacity'
            border.setCornerRadius(10);
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                tabLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(border);
            } else {
                tabLayout.setBackground(border);
            }

            actionButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(final View v) {

                    context[0] = v.getContext();
                    Intent i = new Intent(ViewProduct.this, AddUpdateProduct.class);
                    i.putExtra(EXTRA_ADD_UPDATE, "Update");
                    i.putExtra(EXTRA_PRODUCT_ID, productId);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }
            });

            FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(final View v) {
                    context[0] = v.getContext();
                    Intent i = new Intent(ViewProduct.this, AddUpdateEvf.class);
                    i.putExtra(EXTRA_ADD_UPDATE, "Add");
                    i.putExtra(EXTRA_PRODUCT_NO, oldProduct.getProductNo());
                    i.putExtra(EXTRA_PRODUCT_ID, productId);
                    startActivityForResult(i,12);
                    finish();
                }
            });
        }

        private void initializeProduct(long productId) {

            oldProduct = productOps.getProduct(productId); 
            EditTextNo.setText(oldProduct.getProductNo());
            EditTextOrigin.setText(oldProduct.getOrigin());
            tv_cat.setText(oldProduct.getCat);
            tv_Weight.setText(pldProduct.getWeight);
            EditTextSize.setText(oldProduct.getSize());
            EditTextVolume.setText(oldProduct.getVolume());
       }

        private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
        private ViewPager mViewPager;
        public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

            public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
                super(fm);
            }

            @Override

            public Fragment getItem(int position) {

                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        Fragment tab1 = createCustomFragment1();
                        return tab1;
                    case 1:
                        Fragment tab2 = createCustomFragment2();
                        return tab2;
                    case 2:
                        Fragment tab3 = createCustomFragment3();
                        return tab3;
                    case 3:
                        Fragment tab4 = createCustomFragment4();
                        return tab4;
                    default:
                        return null;
                }
            }



            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                // Show 3 total pages.
                return 4;
            }

            @Override
            public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        return "Sales";
                    case 1:
                        return "Oders";
                    case 2:
                        return "Suppliers";
                    case 3:
                        return "Actions";
                }
                return null;
            }

        }

        public Fragment createCustomFragment1(){
            final FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            final Sales salesFrg = new Sales();
            ft.replace(R.id.container, salesFrg);

            final Bundle bdl = new Bundle();
            bdl.putString("productIde", String.valueOf(productId));
            salesFrg.setArguments(bdl);

            ft.commit();
            return salesFrg;
        }

    > createCustomFragment2(),createCustomFragment3(),createCustomFragment4() >looks exactly like createCustomFragment1()

    }
```

Comment: 1) You should set up the views in onCreate instead of onResume. 2) You shouldn't be using fragment transactions if you are using a viewpager. Why are you doing that?

Comment: Thanks @Juan . 1) Moved Views to onCreate(). 2) Transactions came with code to create a bundle which passes values from the host activity to  a fragment in the same activity. I'm no guru, so I'm open for suggestions, please elaborate on 2). Or is there an easier way instead of using bundle?

Comment: Awesome @Juan, I removed the fragment transactions - {final FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();} and its usages. PEACHES!!!